# Google Chrome in CentOS

Tags: linux, google-chrome, centos

In CentOS 6.5  I would like to install Google Chrome, but I am having a problem with that.

I read that this is mainly because Google are using very recent Linux build systems which produce backwards-incompatible binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Enable Google YUM repository:**

Add following to `/etc/yum.repos.d/google.repo` file:

*for 32-bit*

```
[google]
name=Google - i386
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/i386
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

*for 64-bit*

```
[google64]
name=Google - x86_64
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

**2) Install Google Chrome with YUM (as root user)**

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy and run this line :

```
curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst adding a Google Chrome repo works in CentOS 7, the original question mentioned CentOS 6.5, so just a yum repo on its own isn't good enough for that older (but still supported) platform.

Google do indeed use far too "new" compiler tools when building their Google Chrome browser on Linux, resulting in quite frankly avoidable libstdc++ compatibility issues in CentOS 6. The correct answer is to download and run the script I wrote from the site http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/ but note that you must upgrade to at least CentOS 6.6 to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This installs Chrome on any RHEL/CentOS/Amazon Linux variant.

```
curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
```

Refer for more details: https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/

Answer (score 0):

For linux rpms, you can find specific versions of Chrome here:
https://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-CHROME_VERSION.x86_64.rpm

replace CHROME_VERSION with the version you are looking for, e.g. 86.0.4240.198-1